# Minimum number of people such that 2 can be expected to sit next to each other

Tags: pr.probability

We are given a large, round table with $n$ seats. It is easy to see that whenever $p\geq \text{int}(\frac{n}{2}) + 1$ people are seated, at least $2$ people will sit next to each other (here $\text{int}(x)$ denotes the largest integer less or equal than $x$).

Given $n$ seats at a round table, let $s(n)$ be the smallest number so that the probability that at least $2$ people sit next to each other is $\geq 0.5$ when $s(n)$ people choose their places randomly. (That is: first, person number $1$ picks a seat with uniform probability, then number $2$ takes one of the remaining seats with uniform probability, etc.)

Does $\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{s(n)}{n}$ exist, and if yes, what is its value?

(Transferred from https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/162995/minimum-number-of-people-such-that-2-can-be-expected-to-sit-next-to-each-other as I didn't get an answer there.)

Comment: Just use linearity of expectation - I think this doesn't belong here.

Comment: Please explain in an answer why the limit exists, and what its value is, so we can close this question

Comment: @DominicvanderZypen This is not a research-level question in mathematics. As such, not only Anthony is not under an obligation to answer your question, but he ought to vote it down as not being suitable for this forum.

Comment: @BorisBukh I agree he is not under such an obligation. I was just asking whether there is an obvious answer to my question that I have overlooked. If you know the limit I asked for, please let me know it.

Comment: @DominicvanderZypen This is a very basic probability question (undergraduate level). As an experienced user, you know that if someone here asked "What is 2+2?", they would be downvoted and redirected to resources outside MO. Similarly, your question does not belong to this forum, but it would be on-topic at MSE.

Comment: On the link I gave in the question above, my problem was called "tricky" in the comments, and no answer was given. If the question is as basic as you claim, I'm sure you can give me the limit. Please share your wisdom.

Comment: @DominicvanderZypen While I am sympathetic to your plea for assistance, MO is not a place to seek assistance with undergraduate-level material. Not receiving a satisfactory answer on stats.stackexchange.com does not make your question on topic here. Similarly, I should not answer your question as doing so would reward posting off-topic questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some partial answer. Once you fix the first guy then you can see if $k$ persons are seated in the table with distance greater and $1$ then this give by counting the spaces between each one this gives you a partition of $n-k$ in $k$ parts. So the cases that you don't want to count are in correspondence with the ways of summing $n-k$ with $k$ positive integers. This are $n-k-1\choose k-1$, and in total there are $n-1\choose k-1$ cases. At the end you are asking when does $2{n-k-1\choose{ k-1} }< {n-1\choose k-1}$.

Comment: OK - so this implies the limit exists? And how can I calculate its value?